# Flutter get value from provider

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using provider as state management. To use value between multiple files i create a provider like this

```
class globalProvider with ChangeNotifier, DiagnosticableTreeMixin {
  String uuID = "";

  String get _uuID => uuID;

  void changeuuID(id) {
    uuID = id;
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

I am updating value like this

```
   final uuidUpdate = Provider.of<globalProvider>(context, listen: false);
   uuidUpdate.changeuuID(user.uid);
```

Now on other page I need to print uuID value. I try to do like this

```
  print(Provider.of<globalProvider>(context).uuID);
```

But its showing error Tried to listen to a value exposed with provider, from outside of the widget tree.

main.dart

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => globalProvider()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: LoginPage(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Where did you place your `ChangeNotifierProvider` that provides your `globalProvider`? If it's not before `MaterialApp` widget that wraps your application it won't be accessible in the new screens.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add your state up in your widgets tree like:

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => globalProvider (),
        builder: (context, _) {
    return theRestOfTheTreeWidgets();}
    )
```

Comment: It won't be accessible on the new screens (which are pushed with `Navigator`) if you don't place it above `MaterialApp` Widget!

Answer (score 0):

in your main.dart add ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: GlobalProvider) in MultiProvider widget,

Make sure that your class starts with capital letter and let me know if arrow still exists.

Answer (score 0):

You need to print it out with `listen: false` like this,

```
print(Provider.of<globalProvider>(context, listen: false).uuID);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this package

> get_it: ^7.2.0

```
class GlobalProvider with ChangeNotifier, DiagnosticableTreeMixin {
  String _uuID = "";

  String get uuID => _uuID;

  void changeuuID(id) {
    _uuID = id;
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

in your main.dart .please must use Upper cast
and paste the below code in main.dart

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
 await di.init();
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => di.sl<GlobalProvider >()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: LoginPage(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

make a new dart file and paste this code

```
final sl = GetIt.instance;

Future<void> init() async {
    sl.registerFactory(() => GlobalProvider ());
}
```

and I use this init() function in main file already ..just import library